# Combining angled shapes in Photoshop CS6 causes antialiasing on all

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes, anti-aliasing

When I combine two shapes where at least one has a non-right angle or curve, both shapes become anti-aliased.  This appears to be some new to CS6.  Are there any ways to get around this?  The photo below shows two sets of combined shapes, one with a 45 degree angle which causes the blurring and one with right angles which does not blur.!

Example of Blurring

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Photoshop will always anti-alias shapes, which in most situations is what you want. When designing icons and other small-scale items, quite often that's *not* what you want.

One way to avoid the problem is to change your workflow slightly. Create and combine paths, rather than shape layers, then stroke and fill the paths.

- For strokes, use the Pencil tool and "Stroke Path" from the Paths flyout menu.
- For fills, use "Fill Path" and turn off Anti-Alias.

Comment: By recreating the exact same shape from a single path the anti-aliasing did not occur. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Actually all those paths are anti-aliased, the top image and the bottom image. If you look closely you can see the subtle grey line for anti-aliasing.

The difference is an arc or angle will **always** require more anti-aliasing than a straight path.

To assist you can tick the "align edges" option which appears on the Control bar when a Shape Tool is active.

For more tips on adjusting anti-aliasing, please see the following similar threads:

[How do I turn off anti-aliasing while drawing shapes in Photoshop?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1812/how-do-i-turn-off-anti-aliasing-while-drawing-shapes-in-photoshop)

https://superuser.com/questions/375493/can-i-disable-anti-aliasing-in-photoshop

[How can I stop or disable anti-aliasing / feathering in Photoshop?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4641/how-can-i-stop-anti-alias-feathering-within-photoshop)

Comment: The lower shape doesn't have any blurred out edges like the top.  I don't recall this happening in earlier versions which is why I ask

Comment: My overall point was, you can't have an arc or angle **without** anti-aliasing. You need to use the pencil tool and be precise if you do not want any anti-aliasing. The threads I linked to should be enlightening. The vertical in your top image probably shifted a fraction of a point when you combined shapes, causing the anti-aliased vertical edge.