# Creating a Selection in Photoshop with no Feathering or Anti-aliasing

Tags: adobe-photoshop, selections, anti-aliasing

**EDIT: TL;DR I can't get rid of anti-aliasing and/or feathering, even though they are disabled.**

Some visuals, so you can actually see it happen...

First this is me trying to erase, clicking madly; [http://i.imgur.com/lmURwvM.gif](https://i.imgur.com/lmURwvM.gif)

The next is attempting to fill the selection using the pencil; [http://i.imgur.com/6ILgU83.gif](https://i.imgur.com/6ILgU83.gif)

Finally, a pic of the results of a simple 'fill' (100% black); [http://i.imgur.com/1gs4i0t.png](https://i.imgur.com/1gs4i0t.png)

```
     ------------------------------------------------------------
```

Detailed explanation;

I am working with images that require that there be no anti-aliasing or feathering of any kind. The 'jagged' look you can see in the image (end of post), where I have managed it, is the desired result. Photoshop seems to force gradations on me despite attempts to eliminate them.

I have attempted the following settings;

- Brush hardness and opacity of course at 100%
- Anti-alias unchecked, presumably disabled
- Feathering set to minimum possible (.2)
- Edit -> Preferences -> General > "Image Interpolation" set to "Nearest Neighbor (preserve hard edges)" (though I gather this is more for preserving pixel appearance when resizing, thought I'd try it anyway)
- possibly other things I've forgotten...

All of these settings to no avail, as Photoshop simply will not let me draw (or erase) cleanly within a selection. It insists on creating partially opaque pixels surrounding every pixel I am working with, both in and outside of the selection (even when working with a single pixel at a time). The tool I'm using doesn't seem to matter - either brush, pencil or eraser. The method of selection doesn't appear to matter either.

Erasing a single pixel requires some half a dozen clicks as it is gradually erased, partially erasing all of its neighbors as it does so. Say, 80% transparency the first time I click, 60% the second, and so on, meanwhile making all adjacent pixels reduce to partial trans. as well. It's maddening. Can I not simply click on a pixel and have it gone, while NOT simultaneously effecting its neighbors? And can I not simply draw a single pixel (in or out of a selection) and have it 100% opaque, while also not effecting adjacent pixels? What is this behavior, and can it be stopped?

Repeated Google searches havn't answered this for me. Bottom line, what do I need to do to completely stop any and all anti-aliasing and/or feathering, and simply draw a solid, 100% opaque image within a selection?

Example image can be seen here;

[image: example image]

Comment: What exactly is CS?

Comment: Is CS the Adobe Creative Suite?

Comment: Sorry, the software is Photo CS Extended - simply, Photoshop.

Comment: How are you creating your selections? All you should need to do is set feathering to 0 (I'm not sure why you say minimum is 0.2?). I just tested and I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I stop or disable anti-aliasing / feathering in Photoshop?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4641/how-can-i-stop-or-disable-anti-aliasing-feathering-in-photoshop)

Comment: "How are you creating your selections? All you should need to do is set feathering to 0 (I'm not sure why you say minimum is 0.2?). I just tested and I can't reproduce your problem." I get this regardless of selection method (select tool, pen create selection, etc.). And I say minimum is .2 because that is what photoshop says if I try and make it any less than that, you can see the message here; http://i.imgur.com/sfa8ZwI.png

Comment: No, not a duplicate post, just the identical problem from another user that didn't solve the problem. Finding that post via Goggle search is actually what led me here.

Comment: That dialog is **applying** a feather not the initial feather setting. [This](http://imgur.com/jKSj90Z) is where you need to set feather to 0.

Comment: @CAI That doesn't seem to resemble my version, but I'll have to wait until I'm home to be certain. Will include pic when I'm home. I believe this is more what I'm working with though (no anti alias or feather options on the menu/toolbar) http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-Sf8xfkGhhgU/ToqixbTh1ZI/AAAAAAAAAS4/UdtebS5ymu8/s1600/basic+interface.png

Comment: The feather and anti-alias options are only visible when the selection tools are active. They should be there (I believe they are there in all CS versions)

Comment: @CAI _"...the initial feather setting"_ 
Mentioning an 'initial feather setting' seems to imply that you set the feather before you even use the selection tool, but when you say;
_"The feather and anti-alias options are only visible when the selection tools are active"_
seems to mean you have to be actively using the selection tool for said setting to appear. This tells me I'm misunderstanding at least one of the statements, perhaps both. Sorry to be obtuse, I'm simply not sure what you mean. Will still check for the setting you've shown me when I return home though. thx

Comment: The options are only visible after you select the correct tool in the tools panel but you do set them before using those tools.

Comment: @Brad don't forget to accept an answer if you solved your problem. This stops the question popping up in the list of unanswered questions (and helps everyone out with a bit of rep) Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out, at least for this particular pic, that the issue was the pen tool. I was using more than one tool to do some fairly intricate selections, but they began with 'pen tool>make selection'. There is an option that pops up during that process where both anti alias and feather options are, that I completely missed. Anti alias was checked. So far, making the adjustments there (unchecking it) is working for me. Thanks everyone for the suggestions!

Comment: This is what finally solved the issue for me. Thank you so much. I was using multiple selection tools and one of them had anti-aliasing checked. Hours wasted lol.

Answer (score 4):

Create a document 800px X 600px and set resolution to 10 px/in

[image]

You can still see anti aliasing on hard brush stroke.

Undo that

[image: anti aliasing]

Now change Image Mode to Index Colour

[image]

Select Palette to Uniform

[image]

Now painted with hard brush with no effect of anti aliasing or semi transparent pixels.

[image]

Comment: What does setting the document resolution to 10PPI have to do with anything?

Comment: lower resolution for more jagged edges, higher resolution will decrease the jaggedness or adjust resolution as per required.

Comment: Not really—800x600px at 10PPI is exactly the same as 800x600px at 300PPI. Pixels is all that matter.

Comment: Yeah, both will be same as pixel count didn't change. For dimension, I should have taken inches or millimeters :)

Comment: I'm afraid to use indexed color, you have to flatten first (i.e., you cant use layers). I am working with layers.

Comment: Basically, changing to Indexed color fixed the problem. No need to choose Uniform I guess. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using the any of the Selection tools, all you need to do is set **Feather** to 0px and un-check **Anti-alias**:

[image]

If you have a selection with a feather already applied to it (for example, if you use the 'Make Selection...' command on a path there seems to be a minimum feather) you can use **Refine Edge** (**Select → Refine Edge...**).

[image]

Setting the **Contrast** to 100% will give you a hard edge with no feathering. It may not be perfect but if you are stuck with a feathered selection it is the best you will get without manually remaking the selection. You may be able to adjust the other settings to get a better result.

[image]

A better option (as @joojaa pointed out) is to enter Quick Mask Mode (<kbd>Q</kbd>) and use Threshold (**Image → Adjustments → Threshold...**)

[image]

Comment: Well yes i prefer to page to quick selection mode and use threshold, because i can adjust the cutoff value.

Comment: Yes, you are right, threshold is a much better option!

Comment: Threshold did the job! I was trying to do a Color Range selection, and it was giving me a lot of feather. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do this: enlarge the image by 10x, and reduce the size of your selection circle a lot.

The selection-circle-to-pixel-size ratio automatically controls the amount of feathering applied at a soft edge. I don't like it but that's the way photoshop is at the moment. You will have to zoom in and be more precise with the way you outline with the selection tool but at least you won't get a soft selection. Photoshop is trying to be intelligent and match the natural ambiguity of the edge that it detects. I guess that is good in some cases but I agree there really should be a way to finely control it.